# Twitter API search issue with deleted tweets

Tags: twitter

I'm experiencing a problem with the Twitter GET search/tweets method using the 'since_id' parameter. Everything works fine apart from this.

Here is the scenario:

1. There are 2 tweets (id '1' and '2').
2. The last tweet (id '2') is deleted and a new tweet (id '3') is created.
3. If I do 'GET search/tweets?q=since_id:2' it doesn't return the new created feed :(

Has anyone experienced and solved this?

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Using the User timeline method this problem disappeared.